# monitor webpage with applescript

Tags: applescript

So I'm trying to watch a webpage, and when an input form appears I need to input my name. I came up with this, but clearly not correct.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    set textToType to "Peter"
    repeat
        if execute javascript "document.getElementById('Account_UserName') then
            execute javascript "document.getElementById('Account_UserName').focus();"
            keystroke textToType
            keystroke return
        end if
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this page for testing:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Test Page</title>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 10em;
                padding: 2em;
                border: solid .2em green;
            }
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Page</h1>
        <form action="http://www.example.com/">
            <input type="text" name="Account_UserName" id="Account_UserName">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The first issue is that in order to focus, Chrome appears to need the tab/window combination specified. So, instead of “execute javascript”, it is “execute tabSpecifier javascript”.

The second issue is that the AppleScript needs a boolean to check on; it doesn’t seem to handle the return value of “execute javascript” very well.

The third issue is that without a delay in the loop, AppleScript will lock up the app.

And finally, “keystroke” needs to be wrapped in a “tell application” for “System Events”.

Here’s an example that should get you started:

```
set textToType to "Peter"
set fieldName to "Account_UserName"

tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat
        try
            --Chrome needs to have a tab to execute JavaScript in
            set myTab to tab 1 of window 1
            set fieldNameCheck to execute myTab javascript "nameField=document.getElementById('" & fieldName & "');nameField.name"
            if fieldNameCheck is equal to fieldName then
                execute myTab javascript "document.getElementById('" & fieldName & "').focus();"

                --activate the window so that System Events can type into it
                activate myTab
                tell application "System Events"
                    keystroke textToType
                    keystroke return
                end tell
            end if
        end try

        --sleep a second between loop, or AppleScript will eventually lock up the app
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

I opened Chrome, started browsing the web, and started running this script; when I navigated to the test page, it immediately detected that I was there, filled out the form, and submitted it to example.com.

Note that in real life, you might find it easier to perform the entire script in JavaScript using “javascript execute”, since you should be able to set the value and submit the form there.